# Why search function returns None?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

As a schoolwork, I've got to build a Binary Search Tree from given array and make a few functions on top of it. 
The `search()` function doesn't work and I don't know why, it keeps returning `None`, even though it should return either `True` or `False`.
There might be a error in my code in building functions, but the uploading system writes, that it successfully builds a tree.

```
visited = 0

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = value


class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(value)
        else:
            self._insert(value, self.root)

    def _insert(self, value, curNode):
        if value < curNode.data:
            if curNode.left is None:
                curNode.left = Node(value)
            else:
                self._insert(value, curNode.left)
        else:
            if curNode.right is None:
                curNode.right = Node(value)
            else:
                self._insert(value, curNode.right)

    def fromArray(self, array):
        for i in range(len(array) - 1):
            value = array[i]
            self.insert(value)
            i += 1

    def search(self, value):
        global visited
        if self.root.data is None:
            visited += 1
            return False
        else:
            return self._search(value, self.root)

    def _search(self, value, curNode):
        global visited
        if value == curNode.data:
            visited += 1
            return True
        elif value < curNode.data and curNode.left is not None:
            self._search(value, curNode.left)
        elif value > curNode.data and curNode.right is not None:
            self._search(value, curNode.right)
        else:
            return False

    def min(self):
        global visited
        curNode = self.root
        while curNode.left is not None:
            visited += 1
            curNode = curNode.left
        return curNode

    def max(self):
        global visited
        curNode = self.root
        while curNode.right is not None:
            visited += 1
            curNode = curNode.right
        return curNode

    def visitedNodes(self):
        return visited
```

Comment: You should probably make the visited variable a property  of the tree

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how, so I made it a global

Comment: Move it into the `__init__` like the other ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `_search()` function. It doesn't return anything in either the second or third test case. If you don't explicitly define a `return` in python, the method returns `None`.

A fix might be

```
def _search(self, value, curNode):
    global visited
    if value == curNode.data:
        visited += 1
        return True
    elif value < curNode.data and curNode.left is not None:
        return self._search(value, curNode.left)
    elif value > curNode.data and curNode.right is not None:
        return self._search(value, curNode.right)
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's it! Thank you, sir.